# Got the error File type is not supported when uploading a file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, net-http

```
 url = URI("https://api.podium.com/v4/messages/attachment")
      https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
      https.use_ssl = true
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
      request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data"
      request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{access_token}"
      form_data = [["attachment",File.open('D:\proj\v5\ap\fl\Screenshot (1).png')],['data', "#{request_data}"]]
      request.set_form(form_data, 'multipart/form-data')
      response = https.request(request)
      response_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      if response.code == '200' || response.code == '201'
          return response_body,'success'
      else
           return response_body,"#{response.message}"
      end
      rescue Exception => ex
        return ex,'Exception'
     end
```

**
When i am sending the request i got the error like

{"code"=>"invalid_request_values", "message"=>"File type is not supported.", "moreInfo"=>"https://docs.podium.com/docs/errors#invalid_request_values"}
**

Comment: The `podium` service you are making the request to is throwing this error. There is nothing wrong syntax-wise that we can help you with. You should check their documentation and see if they support `png` files or not. If they do, there might be some extra parameters that you need to pass.

Comment: See [the podium documentation](https://help.podium.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039896873-Sending-Messages#Attach%20media%20to%20a%20message) for a list of supported file types and their restrictions.

Comment: Yes it is supporting .pnd and .jpg and i have taken these code from postman snippet and it is running fine in postman but not ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you could try:

1. The podium documentation says that the images cannot be above 5mb in size. You can verify if this is the case.

https://help.podium.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039896873-Sending-Messages#Attach%20media%20to%20a%20message

2. I noticed the code snippet you've shared does set have this line as mentioned in their documentation here https://docs.podium.com/reference/messagesend_with_attachment

```
request["accept"] = 'application/json'
```

Maybe adding this header might fix it for you, as you are saying that it is working for you in Postman but not in Ruby.

3. Try uploading the file from the API Doc reference page itself and check out the code sample they provide there. There are some differences in the code sample you've shared, and the one that podium shows in their doc.

Comment: 1. Yes it below 5MB in size
2. I have added request["accept"] = 'application/json' but same error
3. I have also used  code sample they provide there but that is also not working.